# Use nuget external tool in powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, nuget, .net-core

Some nuget packages add external tools eg. OpenCover installs its executables in `$env:USERPROFILE\.nuget\packages\opencover\<version>\tools`. These can be executed from the PackageManager console in Visual Studio. eg.

```
PM> OpenCover.Console.exe
```

But I'm having no luck getting the command running outside PackageManager (specifically, I'm trying to run `OpenCover.Console.exe` in a PowerShell build script).

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-console#setting-up-a-nuget-powershell-profile these tools are available to a Powershell nuget profile. But I can't seem to find a way to specify a profile file to use in a Powershell session (`Powershell` doesn't take a profile file arg and sourcing the profile file in a session throws an error).

Any suggestions how to run these nuget tools outside of PackageManager?

Comment: well, what error does sourcing it throw?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how OpenCover works, but nuget is not part of the normal msbuild toolchain; its executed separately. Most builds I've worked with, the nuget restore step is separate, executed before the msbuild step.

Also, nuget is not "installed" in your OS, nor should you rely on it being available on a machine - it's just a standalone tool. You have to download, extract and add it to your path, or execute it directly - something like this (powershell):

```
$args = @("restore", "D:\path\to\my\build.sln")
& "D:\path\to\nuget.exe" $args
```

Comment: I'm actually not trying to run `nuget` but an external tool installed as a nuget package.